# Is it possible to return the elements of a list one by one every time the code is ran?

Tags: python, list

I would like to do something along the lines of what random.choice(range(12)) does, but instead of returning one random choice every time the code is ran, I would like one element whenever the code is ran, but in increasing order. Is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

That's what iterators are for:

```
>>> valuemaker = iter(range(12))  # Or any other iterable you want to statefully pull a value at a time from
>>> print(next(valuemaker))
0
>>> print(next(valuemaker))
1
>>> print(next(valuemaker))
2
```

etc. The iterator itself is stateful, so each time you call `next` on it it resumes from the last point and produces the next value. Obviously if you want to pull them all one by one in a loop you could just use a `for` loop (and skip calling `iter`, since the `for` does it implicitly). If you want the values in random order, just call `random.shuffle` on the `list` before creating the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Trivially:

```py
def get_next():
    for item in [1, 2, 17, 42]:
        yield item
```